# Is there a way I can suppress "defaultProps will be removed" warnings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js

I have an existing next.js codebase with multiple bugs that need fixing. Currently the console is filled with:

```
Warning: ArrowLeftInline: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. 
Warning: GithubInline: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
Warning: GlobeInline: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
```

These seem to be coming from Reactified-SVG files. Eg, there's no GlobeInline component, but only:

```
import Globe from "../../public/src/img/icons/Globe.inline.svg";
```

Which is simply a react-ified SVG file:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="globe" class="svg-inline--fa fa-globe fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M336.5 160C322 70.7 287.8 8 248 8s-74 62.7-88.5 152h177zM152 256c0 22.2 1.2 43.5 3.3 64h185.3c2.1-20.5 3.3-41.8 3.3-64s-1.2-43.5-3.3-64H155.3c-2.1 20.5-3.3 41.8-3.3 64zm324.7-96c-28.6-67.9-86.5-120.4-158-141.6 24.4 33.8 41.2 84.7 50 141.6h108zM177.2 18.4C105.8 39.6 47.8 92.1 19.3 160h108c8.7-56.9 25.5-107.8 49.9-141.6zM487.4 192H372.7c2.1 21 3.3 42.5 3.3 64s-1.2 43-3.3 64h114.6c5.5-20.5 8.6-41.8 8.6-64s-3.1-43.5-8.5-64zM120 256c0-21.5 1.2-43 3.3-64H8.6C3.2 212.5 0 233.8 0 256s3.2 43.5 8.6 64h114.6c-2-21-3.2-42.5-3.2-64zm39.5 96c14.5 89.3 48.7 152 88.5 152s74-62.7 88.5-152h-177zm159.3 141.6c71.4-21.2 129.4-73.7 158-141.6h-108c-8.8 56.9-25.6 107.8-50 141.6zM19.3 352c28.6 67.9 86.5 120.4 158 141.6-24.4-33.8-41.2-84.7-50-141.6h-108z"></path></svg>
```

**Why does React/Next think I am using `defaultProps` for these SVG files?**

**How can I fix or suppress the warnings so I can read the console?**